# Is it possible to suppress CheckOut/CheckIn dialogs in Extendscript?

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I have a script with a function that checks out a document's first story. When I run this, a dialog pops up asking whether I want to update the text to the latest version. Since this function runs several times per run of the script, I want to suppress this dialog by replying yes every time. Is there a way to automatically say yes to these dialogs as they come up, or just suppress them with an automatic response?

```
function doccheckout(doc) {
    // get the main story
    var stories = doc.stories
    var story = stories.firstItem()
    // check out the main story
    story.checkOut()
    }
```

The same thing happens when I close out the document with `document.checkIn()`, so I'd like to suppress that one as well, but I assume any solution to the first part will be applicable to the second.

Relevant popups

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to disable the user interaction:

```
app.scriptPreferences.userInteractionLevel = UserInteractionLevels.NEVER_INTERACT;
// your code here
//
// at the end of your script reset it to the default
app.scriptPreferences.userInteractionLevel = UserInteractionLevels.INTERACT_WITH_ALL;
```

Comment: It seems last line should be `UserInteractionLevels.INTERACT_WITH_ALL` .

Comment: Thanks @milligramme

Comment: I get `UserInteractionLevels is undefined` for some reason. The Object Model Viewer shows that it exists, though. [This old thread](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/871757) suggest using `app.displayDialogs`, which doesn't seem to be in the latest 8.0 object model.

Comment: Nevermind, I just didn't have indesign selected in the extendscript toolkit.